# How can I retrieve the number of decimals of a token with RPC?

Tags: go-ethereum, tokens, erc-20, json-rpc, rpc

There doesn't seem any obligation in the [ERC20 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ERC20) to provide the number of decimals anywhere, yet etherscan and all other services can automatically determine the number of decimals of a token. How is that done?

Is there an automated way (through RPC to geth) to get the number of decimals of a token defined by some contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an ERC20 token, number of decimals are defined in the contract deployed on the address of that token.

Example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
import 'zeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol';
import 'zeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20.sol';
contract ExampleCoin is ERC20 {
  using SafeMath for uint256;
  string public symbol = "EXAMPLE";
  string public name = "ExampleCoin";
  uint8 public decimals = 18;
  mapping (address => uint256) balances;
  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
  function ExampleCoin() public {
    balances[msg.sender] = 1000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));
    totalSupply = 1000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));
  }
}
```

Every ERC20 contract follows same set of standards. All of them have a public decimal value (Thank you open Zeppelin)

All you need is to read that decimal value from the contract's address.

What is even more exciting, you can use generic ABI to connect to any ERC20 contract address and fetch its decimal value. [See here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29914/getting-abi-data-for-erc20-tokens-programatically-with-web3)

I hope this helps!

Comment: What confuses me here is that we're assuming that there's a member variable called "decimals" that has the number of decimals... but this is not in the ERC20 standard! How safe is it to make this assumption?

Comment: please have a read on ERC20 standards its there along with name and ticker: https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard

Comment: As you see there "Some of the tokens include further information describing the token contract", not all tokens implement "decimals" member variable. It seems not to be obligatory. But then what you're saying is that I have to assume that this value is there.

Comment: Yes, I haven't come across a erc20 token that does not use it because it is quite necessary to conduct an ICO exchange for ethereum . Even in ethereum 10 ^ 18 Wei = 1 Ether. You can always keep a simple check and show the user if it doesn't exist for the contract but then again I will emphasise on the fact that is not the usual standard ice are conducted on.

Comment: Last question, if you don't mind. Is it possible to use RPC with the generic ABI like you mentioned? Because from what I see, it uses web3 interface in the link you provided, and I only use json rpc.

Comment: Sure you can look into eth_call: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_call

Comment: I use already `eth_call` to call functions like `balanceOf` and `transfer`. But this is not for member variables, now is it? If I understand correctly, `eth_call` is for functions, and decimals is not a callable, right?

Comment: you can access methods and public variables of an ABI

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're saying that using `eth_call` on a public member variable using its name as a signature will return its value. To do this, I'll hash `decimals` with keccak-256 (like I do with the others, except that the others are functions where signatures are like `balanceOf(address)`) and put that directly in `eth_call`. Hopefully that'll retrieve that value.

Comment: Getters for public variables are automatically created by the compiler. so you need to call decimal()  (see the link I attached in the answer)

Comment: Oh, thanks for that piece of info! I saw the link, but it's so confusing for me because I can't distinguish web3 stuff from standard ethereum stuff. I'll use the signature `decimals()` then.

Comment: and mention decimals in ABI like the link did