# Check when Add Liquidity ETH is called on a token from a Uniswap Pair

Tags: web3.py, uniswap

I have a list of token addresses that I would like to poll for when the `Add Liquidity ETH` method is called. I know that you can access contract events by using:

```
web3 = Web3(my_provider)
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=token_address, abi=token_abi) 
contract.events.event_name_here
```

However, two things seem unclear to me...

1. Some tokens aren't verified contracts and therefor do not have an ABI listed. And even if they are and do have an ABI listed. It seems that it is inconsistent whether or not that method is listed in there. So how is it possible to get the contract when the ABI is not listed?
2. If you assume what the ABI is by using the standard ERC20 ABI as listed in an answer here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/29929. Wouldn't you still run in to the same issue as above where the contract will not show you the `Add Liquidity ETH` method.

To provide an example if we look at [APAD](https://etherscan.io/address/0xf722B7b4876Cbba560846556dD1F5932eb503DE2). You can see liquidity was added about a week ago as shown in the screenshot here:
[image]

In APAD's case, their method is called `addLiquidity` and it can be seen in their source code and ABI. So I understand that this differs a little bit from other contracts that call it `addLiquidityETH` or whatever else.

What is the best way to detect when this event happens? Am I on the right track with trying to do this by using `contract.events`? If so how would I check for when that event happens?

**EDIT**

With some help from the answer below I am getting further along. I am able to detect transfers that are being made by doing the following:

```
token_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=created_pair.get_token_address(weth_contract), 
        abi=standard_erc20_abi)
check_liquidity_filter = token_contract.events.Transfer.createFilter(fromBlock='latest')

asyncio.run(await log_liquidity(check_liquidity_filter, 2))
```

And here is my `log_liquidity` method:

```
async def log_liquidity(event_filter, poll_interval):
    while True:
        print("checking for liquidity")
        for res in event_filter.get_new_entries():
            print(Web3.toJSON(res))
        await asyncio.sleep(poll_interval)
```

In my most recent example I pulled the token data for this pairing:

token0: https://etherscan.io/address/0x694aeb98D02bf69a20a1bA754F07acfA2F4D8f9E

token1: https://etherscan.io/address/0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2

pair: https://etherscan.io/address/0x2297cfc74CcD5880d835d1009Bd6328D3D9E62e3

`Token1` being `WETH` and `Token0` being the new Token in question.

I eventually picked up the following event that happened:

```
{
    "args": {
        "from": "0x2297cfc74CcD5880d835d1009Bd6328D3D9E62e3", 
        "to": "0x970075Ffb8feCaA79135c385dB8461dFF488c96B",
        "value": 26448300574725940621084517}, "event": "Transfer",
        "logIndex": 13, 
        "transactionIndex": 13, 
        "transactionHash": "0xefb43d7c033a6b6fe1aeda8812c1a4a1c2b0a7db2bb54cbffc56b3a06405c210", 
        "address": "0x694aeb98D02bf69a20a1bA754F07acfA2F4D8f9E", 
        "blockHash": "0x2c33968dd4f2fcd70214a019903ea00ea61cbfbff896b12d913dd29c6580f9ad", 
        "blockNumber": 14420431
    }
}
```

This does not seem to line up with the initial liquidity being added from the transaction here:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x18efca59fefef67da7512da180ed29fd564931d71f7bf81114f3a2e88721c1a7

1. It does not seem to be the correct block number.
2. The `To address` in the pair seems to be the pairing address, but this is supposed to be the `from address`?

Answer (score 4):

`0x60806040` represents the constructor, and `Add Liquidity` represents a function from APAD that adds Liquidity by calling UniswapV2's function

```
function addLiquidity(uint256 tokens) external payable onlyOwner() liquidityAdd {
    _mint(address(this), tokens);
    _approve(address(this), address(_router), tokens);

    _router.addLiquidityETH{value: msg.value}(
        address(this),
        tokens,
        0,
        0,
        owner(),
        block.timestamp
    );
}
```

To track all liquidity deposits, you can just filter this event:

```
Transfer (address from, address to, uint256 value)
```

where `address to` is the liquidity pool.

And the same way, for all liquidity withdrawals, you can filter to `address from` where `from` is the liquidity pool.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is beginning to become a bit clearer to me. However, how would I be able to filter on the even of the token if I do not have the ABI?

Comment: Sorry, event* not even...

Comment: If it follows the ERC20 standard and it does, you should be able to get this event.
all ERC20 should emit this `event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value)` based on EIP20 https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20

Comment: Thanks again for responding. i took what you mentioned and tried to implement what I thought you meant. However, some things are still a little unclear to me. I updated my questions with an `Edit`. Could you please take a look and tell me where I am going wrong? Thank you!